# Do something before action on Web API 2

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api2, decorator, interceptor

I want to do something before some of the actions of my Web API. Like throw an error...

```
public class OnlyAuthorized : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (!IsValidAuthorization(actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.Authorization?.Parameter))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        actionExecutedContext.Response?.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    public bool IsValidAuthorization(string token)
    {
        return token != null;
    }
}
```

But it is being executed after the action, instead of before it. So the action logic is always being reached despite sometimes, the request is not authorized to execute the action.

How can I do this?

If is not possible to do this with attributes I think I can deal with a solution where I will be able to intercept all POST requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You override `OnActionExecuted` instead of `OnActionExecuting`
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

`OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)`: Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework after the action method executes.

`OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)`: Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework before the action method executes